# Separar por número y texto acorde a mi columna con varios registros en Python (Anaconda)

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter, anaconda

Estoy tratando de separar una columna que contiene números de serie y nombre de varios productos pero no he podido realizarlo en Python, ¿tiene alguien alguna idea de como hacerlo? En excel lo hago por medio de Texto en columnas>"De ancho Fijo" y luego ajusto usando el mouse a partir de donde aparece el texto, en Python he tratado por medio de:

```
df=pd.read_csv(ejemplo)
df.head()
name=df["Code name_supp"].str.split(expand=True)
#name.columns=['Code_producto', 'Nombre de producto']
name
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
943933  PAOE    HOHO    EO  HE  PW  None    None    None
943933  PAOE    HOHO    EO  HE  PW  None    None    None
943933  PAOE    HOHO    EO  HE  PW  None    None    None
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Sin embargo me arroja la separación por todos los espacios que encuentra

Dejo una parte de los datos, esperando alguien pueda ayudarme:

Code name_product

943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
943933     PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

933337     HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW

3990 IGHUETJIOE UGIHOE HE PIE

3990 IGHUETJIOE UGIHOE HE PIE

3990 IGHUETJIOE UGIHOE HE PIE

2830 RTHTTTGIOE CGTHOEBE PUE

Saludos

Comment: Buen día, no es claro lo que deseas lograr, de los datos que pusiste ¿Cuál es el número de serie y cuál es el nombre del producto? ¿Ambos aparecen siempre en la misma posición en el `string`? Por ejemplo, número de serie, espacio nombre?

Comment: correcto ambos aparecen en el string, en la misma columna aparecen los códigos y nombres de productos: es decir: 051515 GTRRA ASAS ASAS, la parte del texto tiene espacios cómo coloqué en la pregunta

Comment: Pero mis preguntas siguen sin ser respondidas, en tu ejemplo. El número de serie son solo números? Es decir, los primeros 6 caracteres? Todo lo demás es el nombre? En todas las filas aparece el número de serie y el nombre en el mismo orden o hay ocasiones que se invierten? La longitud del número de serie siempre es el mismo número de caracteres? El separador entre números de serie y nombres siempre es un espacio en blanco?

Comment: siempre es número de serie y producto (nunca se invierten), pero no siempre son 6 caracteres pueden ser menos (al menos 3)

Comment: Y el separador siempre es un espacio en blanco?

Comment: umm creo que no siempre pero igual la respuesta que me dieron ya lo solucionó. Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, en tu caso yo creo que lo más fácil es utilizar [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), tal como lo habías pensado pero agregando el argumento `n`

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['123 AABBCC DD EE FF', '456789 A BCD FGH','02 ABCD', '1 FGCH', '943933 PAOE HOHO EO HE PW', '933337 HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW']})
print(df['Data'].str.split(n=1, expand=True))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
        0                         1
0     123           AABBCC DD EE FF
1  456789                 A BCD FGH
2      02                      ABCD
3       1                      FGCH
4  943933        PAOE HOHO EO HE PW
5  933337  HOIW POAAEPTIOG EO HE PW
```

Lo que hace el argumento `n` es limitar el número de veces que va a dividir el `string` con el caracter o `regex` configurado en el argumento `pat` (Cuyo valor por defecto es el espacio en blanco).

Comment: Excelente!! justo muchas gracias! esa solución es de todo un crack!

Comment: No hay de que. Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Si el separador fuera diferente, como lo pusiste en tu comentario, puedes utilizar el argumento `pat` para generar un patrón por ejemplo con un `regex`, lo demás funcionaría de igual forma.